# PHP Packet Sending with defined socket

Tags: php, sockets

I am wanting to send a packet to a server using PHP. I am trying to figure out how to conect with a predetermined IP, port and socket id. However, my code does not seem to be working properly, although no error is being shown.

```
function SendData($data){ 
$ip = "1.1.1.1"; 
$port = 31000; 
$my_sock = '525'
$sock = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout); 
    if(!is_resource($sock)){ 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        fputs($sock, $data); 
        return true; 
    } 
SendData("@E"); 
SendData("DJ");  

fclose($sock); 
}
```

I am also considering doing this in Javascript, if possible. Whichever way works best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't your `SendData` function go into infinite recursion? Something like:

```
SendData('X')
    fsockopen(...)
    SendData('@E')
        fsockopen(...)
        SendData('@E')
            fsockopen(...)
            SendData('@E')
                ...
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for that I have placed SendData after the function, however, the problem is it doesn't seem to be connecting to the proper settings and socket.

Comment: Look at the examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php - it's pretty simple.